# Pattern to restrict dot at the end(before @) in email using HTML5

Tags: html, html-email

Need to write HTML5 pattern which will restrict below email format.

```
test.@example.com. --> Need to restrict dot at the end

 test.test@example.com  --> this should be allowed

 test.test.@example.com --> Need to be restricted(because of dot at the end)
```

I have written pattern like this,

```
pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+@(.+)\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$"
```

but I want to write it in more optimised way.

Please help me to write it in optimised way.

Comment: How is this related to building HTML emails (if not, remove the tag)? What language are you using regex with?

Comment: @nathan I want to restrict some email address in HTML itself. So, I have written the pattern ==> pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+[^.]+@(.+)\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$". Now it didn't have repeated structure.